# java.sql.SQLException: Column Index out of range, 0 < 1. using prepared statement

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

I am using a prepared statement to insert data in a  database. After I have inserted one row normally, the program keeps showing the "column index out of range exception". The number of columns and inserted values equals. The problem might be the cursor not moving to the next line, but in other similar programs this wasn't an issue.
The screenshot of the code is in the link, I cannot post an image.
[inserting values using prepared statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqXAg.png)

Comment: Could you provide the syntax of said prepared statement?

Comment: The image is under the link. I am new here and I cannot post an image directly without reputation.